# Ember-data lazy load association with "links" attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model Teacher which has many Students. The models are defined as follows:

```
App.Teacher = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  students: DS.hasMany('student')
});

App.Student = DS.Model.extend({
  teacher: DS.belongsTo('teacher'),
});
```

When a Teacher logs in, the server returns a JSON representation of the Teacher:

```
{
  id: 1,
  email: "abc@example.com",
  links: {
    students: /teacher/1/students
  }
}
```

In the controller for login, I then push this data into the store and store it in a property of the Session controller:

```
this.set('currentUser', this.get('store').push('teacher', teacherJson))
```

I want to lazy-load the `students` association so I used the "links" format as defined in the API (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push). So, ideally, whenever I would call

```
App.SessionController.get('currentUser').get('students')
```

it would load the associated `students` by sending a GET request to `/teacher/1/students`. But that never happens. Why is the request not triggered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. I had to add a property `async: true` to the `students` association in the model for `Teacher`:

```
App.Teacher = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  students: DS.hasMany('student', { async: true })
});
```