# Emberdata How to make a request on a dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is my router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('merchant', { path:'/merchant/:id' }, function() {
    this.route('product-tag');
```

Currently my api works like this. So I'm trying to get all the product tags that belong to merchant with id: 1781.

http://localhost:3001/merchant/1781/product_tags

The closest I've gotten is using a the product-tag route doing something like this:

```
model: function() {
  debugger;
  var parentModel = this.modelFor('merchant').merchant;
  return this.store.find('product-tag', { merchant_id: parentModel.id});
}
```

This will generate a request:

http://localhost:3000/product_tags?merchant_id=1781

I'd assume that because product_tag is a subroute of merchant it'd take into account the dynamic segment of merchant but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks for the help.

My models are as follows:

Merchant:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user_id: DS.attr('number'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('product-tag', {async: true})
});
```

product-tag:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  merchant: DS.belongsTo('merchant', {async: true}),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  active: DS.attr('boolean'),
  taggings_count: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Comment: What do the merchant and product-tag models look like?

Comment: I just updated my post. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application routes are unrelated to the API endpoints Ember Data will make requests to. Adapters will build the API request per model.

If you have control of the API server, the easiest way to retrieve `merchant`'s `product tags` is to send a link with your `merchant` payload. I don't know what format your API uses, but should be something like:

```
"merchant": {
  "id": "1",
  "user_id": "10"
  "links": {
    "product-tags": "http://localhost:3001/merchant/1781/product_tags"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this worked perfectly!
This was also a good post on making sure the relationship is async:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812730/ember-data-lazy-load-association-with-links-attribute

Answer (score 1):

[model](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) hook has two arguments. The first one should content dynamic segments. So, something like this should work:

```
//Router
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('merchant', { path:'/merchant/:merchant_id' }, function() {
    this.route('product-tag');

//Route
model: function(params) {
  return this.store.find('product-tag', { merchant_id: params.merchant_id});
}
```

As for the second part of your question, ember data doesn't support nested URLs. [Discussion on this subject](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/nested-urls-for-ember-datas-restadapter-proposal/5290)